# extract sound from a fla

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

There is an .fla file that has a sound wave in it's library. However I do not have this sound wave saved on my computer so I can not edit or open this sound in another application. I was wanting to know if its possible to extract this *.wav file from out of the fla library? I did some research and they said to goto export movie and export it as an *.wav file. However I tried this it exported the whole fla file as one big *.wav dud. I tried to play it and nothing happened which makes sense.

Is it possible to extract .wave files from a .fla library. if so, can someone elaborate more on how to go about doing so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried to export was WAV, but couldn't find the option.

Don't know if it will help, because what I did is a bit long winded, but here goes:

1. I imported a .WAV file into the library
2. I've set it on the main timeline(as if you were to copy your wav file to new document and place it on the timeline) and set it to Stream
3. I've made the stage size 1 X 1 pixels ( not sure if necessary though :))
4. I've chosen File > Export Movie > QuickTime
5. In the QuickTime settings I've ticked off *Video* and *Prepare for Internet Streaming*
6. I've noticed the quicktime movie was the exact size as the wav file, not sure if it's a coincidence. I imported it into Soundbooth and Saved it as a wav with the settings it had ( 44100Hz, 16bit, Mono in my case)

HTH,
George

Comment: That worked perfectly. What I did is copied the wav file from the old .fla library and pasted into a new blank fla and put it on the timeline. I think that is what you meant. either way. it didn't seem to long or difficult. I think that worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

Ok I know this is an old post, but if your using cs5 and above all you need to do is copy your .fla, change the extension to .zip, open the .zip  go to file/library and than grab the audio file.

Comment: Upvoted. This worked in CS5, not sure about previous versions of Flash

Comment: I converted an old AS2-era FLA to Flash CS6 for this. But I get a never-ending series of .zip.cpgz files.

Comment: Thanks, it worked for me. Had to extract hundreds of PNGs and MP3s. Using this method it took about 10 minutes to rename, unpack and filter the whole library by neccesary extensions. Probably, you've saved some hours of my life :)

Answer (score 7):

1. Right-click on the asset in the Library -> "Copy"
2. Create a new file
3. Right-click on the Library of the new file -> "Paste"
4. Click and drag the file onto the stage
5. Adjust (expand) the timeline so that it covers the whole audio
6. "File" -> "Export Movie"
7. "WAV Audio"

Answer (score 1):

Thought I would add in my own 2 cents here.
The above answers are entirely correct, however not very efficient if you want to export multiple files.
What I did:

1. Make a duplicate of the .fla file (copy/paste)
2. With this duplicate, rename the file extension to zip
3. Now, extract all files from the zip
4. Navigate to the 'bin' sub-directory of those files you just extracted
5. Inside this bin folder are a bunch of .dat files
6. For each .dat file, simply rename the file extension to .mp3 or .jpg depending on if they were an audio clip or image in the .fla project
7. Tip: to change all to .jpg you could use the command **ren *.dat *.jpg** on the command line (or any variation replacing .jpg with the file extension of your choice)

Comment: In case you don't know which extension each .dat should be renamed with, [this](http://superuser.com/a/274737/381953) may help. Note it's not perfect, though.

Comment: Look at DOMDocument.xml - it contains mapping between name you see in IDE and file in bin folder

Answer (score 0):

I don't think audio assets can be exported from the library directly.

But (assuming you can at least make it play) could you try using some audio capture software?

Answer (score 0):

Since you have the fla file you should open it in flash then from the library you can click "Edit with" and open it in your favorite audio editor.  From there you can save it of to your hard drive.

Comment: i tried that and it said the file does not exist. unable to launch in editor

Answer (score 0):

In flash CS3, i tried the ZIP answer. when i tried, it said the archive was corrupt, then i tried extracting as a .rar instead of .zip, it worked!